# Ajax Error on Datatable using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatable

I have a table and showing data and using Datatables Yajra. This datatables is showing data, and all function is OK. But, sometimes error. 
I am using Laravel 5.2.* and yajra datatable 6.0.*.

And this is the error notification.

[image]

[image]

This is my js code

```
<!-------------------------------------------->
<!-------------- SLAVE VARIABLE -------------->
<!-------------------------------------------->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slave-variable-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
                url: '{{ url("/variable-list/slave-variable/data-slave-variable") }}'
            },
        columns: [
            { data: 'VARIABLE_NAME', name: 'VARIABLE_NAME' },
            { data: 'TYPE', name: 'TYPE' },
            { data: 'ADDRESS', name: 'ADDRESS' },
            { data: 'ACCESS', name: 'ACCESS' },
            { data: 'VALUE', name: 'VALUE' },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            { data: 'checkbox', name: 'checkbox', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]
    });

});
</script>

<!-- DELETE DATA SLAVE_VARIABLE pada view variable-list/slave-variable -->
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteSlaveVariable', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id-variable');
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure to delete this variable?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#0B5EA3',
            cancelButtonColor: '#E6222C',
            confirmButtonText: 'Delete'
        }).then((result) => {
            if(result.value) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/variable-list/slave-variable/delete/" + id,
                    method:"GET",
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#slave-variable-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    });

<!-- AJAX CRUD operations -->
    // Edit a slave_variable
    $(document).on('click', '.modify-modal', function() {
        $('.modal-title').text('Modify Data');
        $('#id_variable_edit').val($(this).data('id-variable'));
        $('#id_slave_edit').val($(this).data('id-slave'));
        $('#id_slot_edit').val($(this).data('id-slot'));
        $('#variable_name_edit').val($(this).data('variable-name'));
        $('#type_edit').val($(this).data('type'));
        $('#access_edit').val($(this).data('access'));
        $('#address_edit').val($(this).data('address'));
        $('#ModifyModal').modal('show');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#bulk_delete', function(){
        var id = [];
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this data?"))
        {
            $('.slave_checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                id.push($(this).val());
            });
            if(id.length > 0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'{{ url("/variable-list/slave-variable/delete-all")}}',
                    method:"GET",
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#slave-variable-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please select atleast one checkbox");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is my slave-variable.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body border-top">
                                    <h5>Slave's Variable Data</h5>
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="slave-variable-table" name="slave-variable-table">
                                                <thead class="bg-light" align="center">
                                                    <tr class="border-1">
                                                        <th class="border-1">NAME</th>
                                                        <th class="border-1">TYPE</th>
                                                        <th class="border-1">ADDRESS</th>
                                                        <th class="border-1">ACCESS</th>
                                                        <th class="border-1">VALUE</th>
                                                        <th class="border-1">ACTION</th>
                                                        <th>
                                                            <button type="button" name="bulk_delete" id="bulk_delete" class="bulk_delete btn btn-danger btn-xs">X</button>
                                                        </th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

This is my routes

```
    //Read data from table SLAVE_VARIABLES to view /variable-list/slave-variable
    Route::get('/variable-list/slave-variable', 'SlaveController@index');
    Route::get('/variable-list/slave-variable/data-slave-variable', 'SlaveController@data');

    //Update data dari table slave_variables
    Route::post('/variable-list/slave-variable/update', 'SlaveController@update');

    //Delete data dari table slave_variables
    Route::get('/variable-list/slave-variable/delete/{ID_VARIABLE}', 'SlaveController@delete');
    Route::get('/variable-list/slave-variable/delete-all', 'SlaveController@deleteAll');
```

And the las is my SlaveController.php

```
public function data()
    {
        $SLAVE_VARIABLES = SlaveModel::select('*');
        return Datatables::of($SLAVE_VARIABLES)
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" 
                    data-id-variable="'.$row->ID_VARIABLE.'"
                    data-id-slave="'.$row->ID_SLAVE.'"
                    data-id-slot="'.$row->ID_SLOT.'"
                    data-variable-name="'.$row->VARIABLE_NAME.'"
                    data-type="'.$row->TYPE.'"
                    data-address="'.$row->ADDRESS.'"
                    data-access="'.$row->ACCESS.'"
                    data-original-title="Modify" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm modify-modal">Modify</a>';
                $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id-variable="'.$row->ID_VARIABLE.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteSlaveVariable">Delete</a>';
                return $btn;
            })
            ->addColumn('checkbox', '<input type="checkbox" name="slave_checkbox[]" class="slave_checkbox" value="{{$ID_VARIABLE}}" />')
            ->make(true);
    }

public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $ID_VARIABLE = $request->ID_VARIABLE;
        $ID_SLAVE = $request->ID_SLAVE;
        $ID_SLOT = $request->ID_SLOT;
        $VARIABLE_NAME = $request->VARIABLE_NAME;
        $TYPE = $request->TYPE;
        $ACCESS = $request->ACCESS;
        $ADDRESS = $request->ADDRESS;

        $slave_variables=SlaveModel::where('ID_VARIABLE','=',$ID_VARIABLE)
        ->update([
            'ID_SLAVE'=>$ID_SLAVE,
            'ID_SLOT' => $ID_SLOT,
            'VARIABLE_NAME' => $request->VARIABLE_NAME,
            'TYPE' => $request->TYPE,
            'ACCESS' => $request->ACCESS,
            'ADDRESS' => $ADDRESS
            ]);

        // alihkan halaman ke halaman /variable-list/slave-variable
        return redirect('/variable-list/slave-variable')
        ->with('update-success', 'Data has ben updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
    *
    * @param  int  $id
    * @return Response
    */

    public function delete($ID_VARIABLE)
    {
        //memilih id
        $SLAVE_VARIABLE = SlaveModel::where('ID_VARIABLE',$ID_VARIABLE);
        if($SLAVE_VARIABLE->delete())
        {
            echo 'Data Deleted';
        }
    }

    function deleteAll(Request $request)
    {
        $ID_VARIABLES = $request->input('id');
        $SLAVE_VARIABLE = SlaveModel::whereIn('ID_VARIABLE', $ID_VARIABLES);
        if($SLAVE_VARIABLE->delete())
        {
            echo 'Data Deleted';
        }
    }
```

Then, this is the display when code run normally
[image]

Please help me guys, thank u.

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Yes. I am using that

Comment: The [package page](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) says that it will not work with that.

Comment: @apokryfos what can I use to build that?

Comment: Try using [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)

Answer (score 1):

**add csrf token and type post in your ajax code**

```
'type': 'POST',
 'data': function ( d ) {
                    d._token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slave-variable-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
               'url' : '{{ url("/variable-list/slave-variable/data-slave-variable") }}',
            'type': 'POST',
            'data': function ( d ) {
                d._token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

            },
        columns: [
            { data: 'VARIABLE_NAME', name: 'VARIABLE_NAME' },
            { data: 'TYPE', name: 'TYPE' },
            { data: 'ADDRESS', name: 'ADDRESS' },
            { data: 'ACCESS', name: 'ACCESS' },
            { data: 'VALUE', name: 'VALUE' },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            { data: 'checkbox', name: 'checkbox', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: please select this answer if its work for you thank you.\

Comment: I have included the code. But, the problem remains. Sometimes a datatable run successfully, sometimes an error.

Answer (score 0):

modify your controller

```php
public function data()
    {
        $SLAVE_VARIABLES = SlaveModel::select('*');
        return Datatables::of($SLAVE_VARIABLES)
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" 
                    data-id-variable="'.$row->ID_VARIABLE.'"
                    data-id-slave="'.$row->ID_SLAVE.'"
                    data-id-slot="'.$row->ID_SLOT.'"
                    data-variable-name="'.$row->VARIABLE_NAME.'"
                    data-type="'.$row->TYPE.'"
                    data-address="'.$row->ADDRESS.'"
                    data-access="'.$row->ACCESS.'"
                    data-original-title="Modify" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm modify-modal">Modify</a>';
                $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id-variable="'.$row->ID_VARIABLE.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteSlaveVariable">Delete</a>';
                return $btn;
            })
            ->addColumn('checkbox', '<input type="checkbox" name="slave_checkbox[]" class="slave_checkbox" value="{{$ID_VARIABLE}}" />')
            ->rawColumns(['checkbox', 'action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
```

i added `->rawColumns(['checkbox', 'action'])` line

it was missing

Comment: if I add that code, I absolutely can not load the data

Comment: can u please show in which url u r getting that ajax error. need to check 500 or 400 error

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to ajax. This normally happens when the desired response is not returned from the server i.e. `JSON` in this case but the html page is returned instead. See your screenshot above where the response is returned page not found wiht `httpnotfoundexception`

So first check if this route/url is really working or not and if working then it's returning the desired response `JSON` to the datatables.